# boost::process::search_path not finding file

Tags: c++, boost-process

The [boost::process::search_path](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost/process/search_path.html) function seems to be unable to find files on some systems.

For example, for the following:

```cpp
boost::process::search_path("example.exe");
```

On some systems, this function will always return an empty string (indicating that it could not find that file), regardless of whether or not `file.txt` exists within the directory or `PATH` variable. Is this an issue with permissions? And if so, how would I fix this?

Edit: Changed example to executable file.

Comment: Since you mentioned that the bug exists only on “some systems”, on which systems does the bug show up?

Comment: @kotatsuyaki I have only tested this on Windows systems, it seems to work on some, and not others.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer did’t solve the author’s problem. See comments below.

---

The [documentation for `boost::process::search_path`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost/process/search_path.html) says that it searches for **an executable** in path. The `file.txt` file may not be (and it shouldn't be) an executable file, which is why `search_path` is not seeing it.

To find **any** file matching a particular name, disregarding whether the file is executable or not, you can use [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) or [`std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) to write your own function to do that. Note that `std::filesystem` is only available starting from C++17. For older standards, `boost::filesystem` may be used instead.

Comment: Hm, I (pretty stupidly) changed it from an executable to a text file. I am indeed trying to find an executable, I'll edit the question. Sorry about that!

Comment: @gam03 I see. I’ll leave this answer as-is as it may still help future readers.